# Downloads folder in Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I accidentally removed my Downloads folder from the dock.

I dragged it back from Finder but it doesn't work like it used to, it's just an ordinary folder now :(

Any ideas how to restore it to it's original glory?

Comment: Right-click it and there should be some options you can set to restore it back to it's original glory.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "original glory"? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "Original glory" you mean making it display the contents in the dock icon, simply right-click on it and under "Display As" chose "Stack".

Comment: I've done that, I'm pretty sure the icon used to show downloads in progress right there in the dock (e.g. a progressbar). Now it just looks like a folder?

Comment: @ConfusedNoob: Nope, I don't think it can do that. It never has for me, anyways. The closest thing might be when you download from the App Store, the application's icon shows the progress.

Comment: Turns out you get the desired effect if you sort by date modified. That means you can see the current file downloading as the icon, including the progress. Thanks!

Comment: @ConfusedNoob: Alright, I'm glad this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You should open "Users" and click on your username folder;
Inside there you should find a folder called "downloads": just drag it on your dock right of the dotted line.

Comment: Did my suggestion work? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it back to normal, do exactly what Pitto said and then after it is back in the dock right click it and choose Stack (This will change it from the conventional folder view to the view you're used to). After that, change the checkmark from Date Modified to Date Added.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you looking for "Fan" view that is default when you install OS X. Right Click on the folder in the Dock and select "Fan" under "View Content As".

Answer (score 0):

In Yosemite, open Finder and right-click on Downloads.  You have an option to "Add to Dock" (as well as an option to "Remove from Sidebar").